# how to save the `Z values` of the data points into a variable for comparing it to a certain z value in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot, contour, gaussian

The `Z value` is calculated in the function using the following code:

```
[marg1,marg2] = meshgrid(marginalLogLikelihood_grid{1},marginalLogLikelihood_grid{2});

[xg,yg] = meshgrid(marginalCDFValues_grid{1},marginalCDFValues_grid{2});
inputMatrix = [reshape(xg,numel(xg),1) reshape(yg,numel(yg),1)];
clear xg yg;

copulaLogLikelihoodVals = gmmCopulaPDF(inputMatrix,gmmObject,xmesh_inverse_space);
Z = reshape(copulaLogLikelihoodVals,size(marg1,1),size(marg1,2));
Z = Z+marg1+marg2;

Z = exp(Z);
```

I want to use this `Z value` to compare it with a particular value of `Z = 4e-5` and eliminate all the points that lie outside the contour line with `Z = 4e-5`.

I've written the following code to generate the contour and the scatter plot

```
plot(givenData(:,1),givenData(:,2),'b.','MarkerSize',3);hold
contour(xgrid,ygrid,Z,[4e-5, 4e-5],'EdgeColor',[1 0 0],'ShowText','on','LineWidth',2);
```

I want to eliminate all the points lying outside the red contour in the image below:
[current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CtIx.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: its not very clear to me (neither in the other post) how `givenData` is related to all the other maths you are doing. You are computing `Z` in a very complicated way using your own math and functions and I don't think anyone of us can figure out what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
lmt = 4e-5;
Z(Z>lmt) = NaN;
```

You can also modify the arrays with indices if you want to remove them altogether

```
lmt = 4e-5;
idx = Z>lmt;

xgrid(idx) = [];
ygrid(idx) = [];
Z(idx) = [];
```

Note that it's not clear whether you want to remove points greater than or less than 4e-5, so modify the inequality as you need.